# What should I do to fix HTTP Request Smuggling on Apache?

Tags: apache

I scaned my site with Burp Suite Proffessional.

It said a vulnerability called "HTTP Request Smuggling" has been detected.

This vulnerability was detected in the August 7, 2019 Burp Suite Professional ver2.1.03.

My server environment is as follows.

- CentOS 7
- Apache 2.4
- PHP 7.3

PortSwigger says how to resolve this problem.

That is by changing the network protocol of the web server from "HTTP/1.1" to "HTTP/2".

https://portswigger.net/web-security/request-smuggling#how-to-prevent-http-request-smuggling-vulnerabilities

So I changed my site with SSL support and then HTTP/2 support as well.

And I scaned again, the "HTTP Request Smuggling" vulnerability was detected AGAIN.

HOW TO FIX THIS?????????

I am NOT interested in what is this problem details or how it works at all.

What I want to know is how to stop detecting this problem.

If you have encountered a similar event, tell me the solution. please?

If possible, I wish what you did something to this, wrote in httpd.conf or php.ini, etc.

Comment: Hello! Did you find a solution? A also faced with this one.

Comment: Hello. It's hard to say, our team has decided to turn a blind eye to this issue as we could not find a solution. We were being asked by a client to solve a high security risk in BurpSuite, but with the latest version of BurpSuite, the priority of this vulnerability has been lowered to medium, so we no longer have to deal with it.

Comment: Ok, BTW I found that this issue fixed in newest versions of tomcat, but I haven't tried yet. If you'll try then tell feedback me pls.

Answer (score 1):

I found that need to improve version of tomcat but I haven't tried yet

[Article about solution](https://blog.qualys.com/vulnerabilities-threat-research/2021/10/27/apache-tomcat-http-request-smuggling-vulnerability-cve-2021-33037)

[image]

Comment: Hmm, our server hasn't install apache tomcat so this solution is not matching my case. but thank you for tell us information :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using end-to-end HTTP/2 communication then that should eliminate the vulnerability. What I mean by this is that HTTP/2 is the only HTTP version used in all HTTP traffic.

Many web architectures has a load balancer or proxy in front of the web server which accepts HTTP/2 traffic. However, many frontend servers rewrite the incoming HTTP/2 traffic into HTTP/1 when it forwards the traffic to the backend server/ web server. When the traffic gets rewritten to HTTP/1 then HTTP request smuggling is possible. More info here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHxVVeM9R-M

I'm posting this quote from James Kettle, a researcher from Portswigger: "you can resolve all variants of this vulnerability by configuring the front-end server to exclusively use HTTP/2 to communicate to back-end systems, or by disabling back-end connection reuse entirely. "

source: https://portswigger.net/research/http-desync-attacks-request-smuggling-reborn